# Server UDP function recvfrom

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, compiler-errors

I have writed the follow code, to implement a server UDP,C++ working in Linux, this is the relative part that get error:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
  int welcomeSocket,newSocket,nBytes;
  struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
  struct sockaddr_in remaddr;
  char buffer[1024];
  socklen_t addrlen;

  welcomeSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
  if(welcomeSocket<0)
  {
    cout<<"Errr"<<endl;
  }
  else
  {
    cout<<"succes"<<endl;
    serverAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port=htons(7891);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    if(bind(welcomeSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr,sizeof(serverAddr))<0)
    {
        cout<<"bind failed"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        addrlen=sizeof(remaddr);
        while(1)
        {
            cout<<"Waiting on port 7891"<<endl;
            recvfrom(welcomeSocket,buffer,1024,0,(struct sockaddr_in*)&remaddr,(socklen_t*)&addrlen);

        }
    }

}
}
```

But when i compile using make, i get an error about the function recvfrom,the error that i have is:

```
invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘void*’ [-fpermissive]
invalid conversion from ‘sockaddr_in*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
cannot convert ‘socklen_t* {aka unsigned int*}’ to ‘sockaddr*’ for  argument ‘5’ to ‘ssize_t recvfrom(int, void*, size_t, int, sockaddr*, socklen_t*)’
```

What is wrong, i don't understand.

Comment: Here is the signature of `ssize_t recvfrom(int, void*, size_t, int, sockaddr*, socklen_t*)` , and for one, where your second arguement is 1024 which should address to buffer... you're passing all wrong arguments!!!!

Comment: Also with this correction, i get the same error on the last argument

Answer (score 1):

After adding the missing `buffer` argument, the issue is with the fifth argument:

```
(struct sockaddr_in*)&remaddr
```

It expects a `struct sockaddr *`:

```
recvfrom(welcomeSocket,buffer,1024,0,(struct sockaddr *)&remaddr,(socklen_t *)&addrlen);
```

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/recvfrom.html states that the fifth argument to `recvfrom()` takes a `struct sockaddr*` instead of a `struct sockaddr_in*`. **However, note that the actual object pointed should preferably be a `struct sockaddr_storage` to handle both IPv6 and IPv4.**

Comment: Thanks i have fixed the problem, i have used the type sokaddr_storage and sockaddr* instead of sockddr_in*